# How to configure Wildfly so that a client will has access to a one bean without a password and to the rest of beans will be required a password?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, wildfly, elytron

I have an EJB client that connects to Wildfly 26.
How should I configure Wildfly so that the client can access bean A without a password and bean B and C require a password?
Hypothetical situation, I connect to the server without logging in,
I get a list of e.g. languages or databases and then I have to log in to work on selected settings.